# How to choose the meaning of a word from many meanings

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary, dictionaries

To increase my vocabulary, I collect words from my daily study and then find them in the Cambridge dictionary. But one word has many meanings. It is sometimes hard to memorize all of them, and it is also time-consuming. But I don't understand which meaning I should chose. So how can I understand which meaning is the most important one that I should memorize?

After reading the comments, I think I should add some more elaboration. 
I have been preparing for the GRE. I have quite a long time on my hands. I have read a book called "Barron's Essential Words for GRE," which gives words together with their meaning. I have also read another book called "Barron's Essential Words for TOEFL". Both of these books list some words with their meanings. These books list one or two meanings. But when I search those words in the dictionary, I find many meanings aside from the meaning they have listed. This makes me confused.

Comment: why i got down vote

Comment: You've been struck by ELU's particular curse, the driveby downvoter.  There are a number of reasons that could be the cause including (1) posting a question that is not abut the language or its usage but instead asks about pedagogical methods, (2) posting a question that can have no definitive answer but only a succession of opinions, (3) posting a question on which you have taken no effort to research an answer, etc.  By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: You don't indicate your native language, but surely it has words with multiple meanings.  How did you learn those?

Comment: Hello, Black Swan. I'm guessing that the downvote occurred because someone thought your question was a bad match for this site. The reality is that learning vocabulary words and meanings from a dictionary is far more hit-or-miss than you might expect. That's because meanings (definitions) appear in order of historical occurrence—the time when each meaning first arose—not on the basis of current usage or importance. There is, as far as I know, no simple way to figure out which meanings to focus on; the position of the most important meanings will vary from one word to the next.

Comment: Your question is off-topic as we can't give you a definitive answer and any answer would be primarily opinion-based. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. I think dangph answered your question below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question now appears on the English Language Learners Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Sven Yargs, Thanks for going to close this  question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the meaning of a word is defined by the context in which it is being used. I'd recommend to collect words from reading different pieces of text, than using a dictionary.

Comment: Ya..i know that it depends on context  but there might be some meanings which are used more than others....

Answer (score 1):

The most common or important definitions are listed first in the dictionary.

For example, [*cat*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cat):

> noun
>
> 1. a small domesticated carnivore, Felis domestica or F. catus, bred in a number of varieties.
> 2. any of several carnivores of the family Felidae, as the lion, tiger, leopard or jaguar, etc.
> 3. Slang.
>    a person, especially a man.
>    a devotee of jazz.

Those are just the first three definitions for cat as a noun. There are 11 more I haven't shown. The first definition is the most important one. The second one is less common. The third one is quite rare. The rest of them are very rare.

(I think it's a waste of time to try to learn words from a word list, by the way. It's more effective to learn words in context. Your brain needs the context so it can associate the words you learn with other knowledge and concepts.)

Comment: Many dictionaries—like the Oxford English Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, and American Heritage—order the definitions within an entry on the basis of when they first appeared in written English, from earliest to latest. In MW's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003), definitions 2 through 7b of _cat_ (after the 1a and 1b feline definitions) are "2: a malicious woman 3: a strong tackle used to hoist an anchor to the cathead of a ship 4a: CATBOAT b: CATAMARAN 5: CAT-O'-NINE-TAILS 6: CATFISH 7a: a player or devotee of jazz b: GUY." This is the historical order in which the meanings appeared.

Comment: ... Compare the order of the definitions I just listed to the order of the definitions in the dictionary you link to in your answer, and you'll see that the two dictionaries use very different ordering systems. Your assertion that dictionary definitions are ordered from most important to least important simply isn't true for many (and arguably the most important) English dictionaries.

Comment: @SvenYargs, okay yes, you are right. I jumped to an unwarranted conclusion. The ordering of definitions does tend to be historical. I think however that historical order will typically correspond more or less to word-frequency order. That is, older senses tend to be more common. I would guess also that some consumer level dictionaries and learner's dictionaries might use word-frequency ordering.

Answer (score 0):

When you search for a word in google, it lists out antonyms and synonyms. Kindly refer to the example sentence given below the word. It will surely help you in understanding the context in which its use. Pickup 5 words to start with and then as you progress collect more words. Also,maintain a diary which you can refer at the end of every week.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for doing this question here. I wanted to delete the question but i am unable to do. I think there is another place which is more appropriate to do this question it  is Stack-exchange ["English Language Learners"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). I have done the question there. Thanks all of you guys who have commented, down voted, up voted and answered my question.

[The question will be found here in "English Language Learners"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89817/how-to-chose-the-meaning-of-a-word-from-many-meanings)